# PHP generate array of random numbers with conditions

Tags: php, random

Is there an easy way with PHP to generate an array with 15 items, all single digit numbers between 1 and 8, in random order, but with the conditions that no digit is next to itself and no pair of digits are next to themselves.

Want to end up with something like: 3 2 7 1 3 2 5 6 7 4 5 1 8 4 8

But not: 3 8 **4 4** 6 7 2 6 7 3 **1 1** 8 5 2

Or: 2 8 6 3 **7 5 7 5** 4 8 1 2 4 1 6

Plan B is to generate a bigger array and then compare the current value with the previous during the foreach function and if the same skip that one and move to the next.  And I am guessing could do the same by comparing the last three to check for pairs.  But then I risk some digits appearing too many times, as the ideal is each digit appearing at least once, but no more than 2 times.

Plan B at the moment, since it seems there might not be an automagical way to do this with PHP:

```
$numbers = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8");
shuffle($numbers);
$cnt=0;
$prvnum=0;
$prvnum2=99;
$prvnum3=89;
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
   if ($number==$prvnum)||($number==$prvnum2)&&($prvnum==$prvnum3) { }
   else {
      // do something with the number
      $cnt++;

      $prvnum3=$prvnum2;
      $prvnum2=$prvnum;
      $prvnum=$number;

      if ($cnt==15) {
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: So you actually have 3 conditions. 3rd being that a number cannot appear more than twice. Your last plan would work well, just add in the 3rd condition by storing an object with the key being the number, and value being the number of occurrence. You can then refer to this object to check and increment the occurrence value.

Comment: peekolo thanks for that suggestion

Comment: No problem. Have a go at it, if it doesn't work, edit and add what you tried and we can all help answer better. :+1:

Comment: @Tom Have a go and comment if there's any issues with my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously play around and edit it into how you need to implement it. But this should work, I've tested myself working fine.

```
//in a current function
$numbers = [];

for($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++){

    $numbers[] = numberGen($numbers);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($numbers);
echo '</pre>';

function numberGen($numbers){
    $num = rand(1, 8);

    $current_values = array_count_values($numbers);

    if(array_key_exists($num, $current_values) && $current_values[$num] == 2){
        return numberGen($numbers);
    }

    if(array_key_exists($index = count($numbers) -1 , $numbers)){

        $index_val = $numbers[$index];

        if($num === $index_val) {

            return numberGen($numbers);
        }
    }

    //if there is no index before 3, no pairs will exist
    if(array_key_exists(count($numbers) -3, $numbers)){

        $first_pair = (string)$numbers[count($numbers) - 3].(string)$numbers[count($numbers) - 2];
        $second_pair = (string)$numbers[count($numbers) - 1].(string)$num;

        if($first_pair === $second_pair){
            return numberGen($numbers);
        }
    }

    return $num;    
}
```

EDIT:: Now including Plan B as requested

Answer (score 0):

Quick possible start. You will need to generate a bigger array, then slice it to your desired length. Require probably one more condition to match your query.

```
<?php
$o=[];
for ($i = 0;$i < 21; $i++){
  $n = rand(0,9);
  (end($o) !== $n) ? $o[] = $n : "";
}
echo join(" ",$o);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built into PHP that will do this but you can write some straight forward code to do so.

The simplest (although probably not the most efficient) is to use a while loop to keep generating numbers until you have generated enough valid digits. Here's one quick and dirty way of doing it.

```
<?php
$numbers=[];
$gen_length = 15;
$i = -1;
while (count($numbers) < $gen_length) {
    $n = rand(0,9);
    if ($i > 0) {
        //Check for duplicate digits
        if ($numbers[$i] == $n)
            continue;
        //Check for duplicate pairs
        if ($i > 2 AND $numbers[$i-2] == $numbers[$i] AND $numbers[$i-1] == $n)
            continue;
        //Insert additional conditions to check for new digits here.
    }
    $numbers[] = $n;
    $i++;
}
print join(" ",$numbers);
```